# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, при parentPanel.add(childPanel);

Tags: java, swing, gui

Не выходит добавить на страницу несколько панелей, как на мокапе (серым обведены JPanels).

Есть основной класс представления (родительская панель)
Класс для визуализации дочерних (левая и правая панели)

Но когда хочу поместить панель в панель, выбрасывается исключение (пробовал отлаживать, объекты все есть на момент добавления):

```
package Views;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Game extends JPanel
    {
        private JPanel main;
        private JPanel leftBoard;
        private JPanel rightBoard;

        public Game()
        {
            add(main);

            Board board1 = new Board(); // JPanel
            Board board2 = new Board();

            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

            leftBoard.add(board1); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 3));
            setSize(new Dimension(800, 480));
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

**Мокап:** https://moqups.com/jilexandr@gmail.com/mQo5v8La

[image: мокап]

**Дерево компонентов**, куда хочу добавить вложенную панель (генерировал с помощью IDE IDEA, new->New form)

[image: дерево]

Debug https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPGaa.png
[image: debug]

**Главный вопрос, почему вылетает Exception, и как правильно сделать структуру как на мокапе?**

Comment: @Vladimir, вы перебарщиваете с правками. Вот тут явно испортили вопрос, переводя его с принятого на ru.so русского языка на неподходящий английский: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/432617/5

Answer (score 1):

```
leftBoard.add(board1); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`NullPointerException` всегда значит ровно одно: вы вызываете метод на поле или переменной, значение которой `null`. В данном случае вы не инициализировали поле `leftBoard`. Нужно добавить что-то вроде:

```
leftBoard = new JPanel();
```

Comment: Вот что там, никаких null: http://i.imgur.com/akGaWWk.png

Answer (score 0):

NPE в строке

```
leftBoard.add(board1);
```

указывает на то, что значение `leftBoard` - `null`. Происходит это из-за того, что вы не инициализируете её никаким образом. Конструктор форм IDEA должен генерировать код инициализации компонентов и помещать его в метод, который называется как-то вроде `$$$setupUI$$$`. Этот метод должен быть вызван до начала работы с компонентами формы. Насколько я помню, IDEA автоматически добавляет вызов этго метода в конструктор формы, так что, скорее всего, вы его удалили. Верните его на место, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Все есть
http://i.imgur.com/akGaWWk.png

Comment: Точно NPE в той строке, что вы указали? В ней NPE может выскочить ровно в двух случаях: если `leftBoard == null` или если `board1 == null`. Инициализацию `board1` в вашем коде я вижу, инициализацию же `leftBoard` - нет. Создаётся впечатление, что вы отлаживаете не то приложение, код которого приведён на скрине. Попробуйте очистить и пересобрать проект, и, почти гарантированно, получите `null` и в отладчике.

Comment: add(leftBoard); вот так ведь работает) значит все есть, проблема в другом

Comment: вроде  решилась проблема [вот источник](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10603083/4698133)